# Mongodb multi document insert ignore custom duplicate field error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to insert 3 recordset from array 1 already exists and 2 are new

e.g:

```
db.products.insert(
   [
     { imagename: "pen1", qty: 21 },
     { imagename: "pen", qty: 20 },
     { imagename: "eraser", qty: 25 }
   ]
)
```

Wherein "{ imagename: "pen", qty: 20 }"` already exists and has unique key 
 on field "imagename" in mongodb

as for now none of them are getting inserted and throwing 
err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: mongotest.mothership.$imagename_1 dup

any suggestion how to insert remaining two ignoring error in single go !

Comment: You can use the continueOnError flag https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#insert

Comment: will check thanks for update

Comment: Hi Sammaye, thanks this works for me
db.collection('song').insert(finalResult, {
    continueOnError: true,
    safe: true
}, function(err, songs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {}
})

Comment: sorry i am unable to post formatted answer !

Answer (score 16):

[Unordered insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#perform-an-unordered-insert) will do the trick

```
db.products.insert(
    [{ imagename: "pen1", qty: 21 },
     { imagename: "pen", qty: 20 },
     { imagename: "eraser", qty: 25 }],
    { ordered: false }
)
```

Comment: this is working on command line but i want to use it in nodejs

Answer (score 11):

Set the `ordered` option to `false`. This is not a trick, but a *reliable* method to achieve it. If errors occur, you may obtain information regarding each of them.

```
const documents = [{name: "Star Wars"}, {name: "Sword Art Online"}];
db.product.insertMany(documents, {ordered: false});
```

If you're using *Mongoose*, use [`Model.insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#insertmany_insertMany).

---

> ### [Perform an Unordered Insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#perform-an-unordered-insert)
>
> The following example performs an unordered insert of three
> documents. **With unordered inserts, if an error occurs during an insert
> of one of the documents, MongoDB continues to insert the remaining
> documents in the array.**

---

> ### Error Handling
>
> Inserts throw a `BulkWriteError` exception.
>
> Excluding *Write Concern* errors, ordered operations stop after an error, while **unordered operations continue to process** any remaining write operations in the queue.

---

> ### `db.collection.insertMany()`
>
> Inserts multiple documents into a collection.
>
> ```
> db.collection.insertMany(
>    [ <document 1> , <document 2>, ... ],
>    {
>       writeConcern: <document>,
>       ordered: <boolean>
>    }
> )
> ```
>
> **`ordered`**: Optional. A boolean specifying whether the mongod instance should perform an ordered or unordered insert. Defaults to `true`.

Answer (score -1):

**Note: ensureIndex is deprecated since v3.0.0**
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/

The following response is left as-is (since `ensure` is now an alias for `create` - both will work at present), but for newer versions you should replace `db.products.ensureIndex` with `db.products.createIndex`.

---

first you need to create unique index.
ex:

```
db.products.ensureIndex({ url: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true, dropDups: true })
```

then insert

```
db.products.insert(
    [{ imagename: "pen", qty: 21 },
     { imagename: "pen", qty: 20 },
     { imagename: "eraser", qty: 25 }],
    { ordered: false }
)
```

it will happen error : E11000 duplicate key error collection: mongotest.products index: imagename_1 dup key :{:'pen'}。
it doesn't matter.
you can try ... catche

```
try {
db.products.insert(
        [{ imagename: "pen", qty: 21 },
         { imagename: "pen", qty: 20 },
         { imagename: "eraser", qty: 25 }],
        { ordered: false }
    )
}catch(e){
print(e)
}
```

Note: when you are calling ensureIndex, you cannot call insert.because ensureIndex is asynchronous, or ensureIndex will fail.